# Neo4j: How could I add bloom?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, profile, activation

I have an activation key for Neo4j Bloom, how could I add it at Neo4j Desktop?
I need to download something before or to put easly the activation key in the user profile area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there should't be any need to download something. It should be enough to:

- Add the activation key in the "User profile" tab (click the "Add license" button)
- Go to your project and click "Add application"
- Find the Bloom card and click the "Add" button